# Android: SDcard permission denied

Tags: android

I tried to write Log in my application, I am getting following exception in some of the Android devices alone, `/mnt/sdcard/Log/log.txt: open failed: ACCES (Permission denied)`. I had used `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission also, but i am getting this error.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + logDir); 
dir.mkdirs(); 

File file = new File(dir, logFileName); 
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(file, true), 8 * 1024)); 
writer.println(message); 
writer.flush(); 
writer.close();
```

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont hardcode the sdcard, you must use `Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)` will let you know if the memory is loaded. Then use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: can you post you code?

Comment: File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + logDir);
dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, logFileName);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
   new FileWriter(file, true), 8 * 1024));
writer.println(message);
writer.flush();
writer.close();

Comment: are you running your application on `Emulator`?

Comment: I made it worked, Checking the SD card availability and performing the operations on SD card solves the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont hardcode the sdcard, you must use `Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)`

will let you know if the memory is loaded. Then use:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proper permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. If so then may I see the code that you used to save write the log.